# Does Face Detection require a SurfaceView to work?

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, face-detection

Using API 14 I have created an Activity which uses face detection successfully (I'm a bit of a newb at this Face Detection stuff).

I don't want to show the preview of the Camera however; I just want to know when the user's face is in front of the camera.  I added a few buttons to make the SurfaceView Visible/Invisible and I found that the face detection stops working when it is INVISIBLE or GONE.

Is there a way to enable the face detection without requiring the SurfaceView in the layout?

Here is how I have coded it:

```
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

            if(mCamera.getParameters().getMaxNumDetectedFaces() >0) {
                mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new Camera.FaceDetectionListener() {
                    @Override public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {

                        if(faces.length > 0) {
                            System.out.println("Found someone");
                        }

                    }
                });
                mCamera.startFaceDetection();
            }
```

To hide the surfaceview I have added a black View. :-)

```
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000"/>
```

I've had a reasonable look around and I haven't found much code using startFaceDetection() yet.

Thanks for any ideas / help.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? I found a project that uses face detection, but trying to only use the face detection without a surface view I have not figured out how to do. https://github.com/ProjPossibility/2014-CSUN-Cam4Blind

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use a dummy **SurfaceTexture** for your purposes.

1. Just create a SurfaceTexture object by passing any integer such as

   ```
    mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(1);
   ```
2. Now, open your camera and do the following:

   ```
   mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); 
    try{ 
     mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
   } 
   catch (IOException t) {
     //Do Something here   
   }
   ```

3) You can do everything else just the same way i.e. using face detection.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and it looks like you're passing the wrong identifier into `Camera.open`. (I don't think the `CameraInfo` constants are camera ids.)

Answer (score 0):

The Camera Preview doesn't get displayed if you omit

```
setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

I have not yet tested this with Face Detection (no 4.0 device and the emulator doesn't yet support it). But it should work.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/EzBgJRetaCo

You could also attempt to use setPreviewTexture(SurfaceTexture st) instead of setPreviewDisplay and use a SurfaceTexture that you can control.

Comment: That reference is rather old material, and outdated. [`setType(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setType%28int%29) has been deprecated in the meantime and according to the documentation setting this flag will have no effect on newer devices: *"this is ignored, this value is set automatically when needed."* `setPreviewTexture(SurfaceTexture)` might work, but is only available in API 11+. Perhaps a combination of both will do the trick? :)